# HTML audio analyzer preventing music from playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to create a visualizer for a music player, using the native audio API. Everything is working well, except when I attach an analyzer, the music stops playing.

See it here, just upload an audiofile to start.

https://codepen.io/jane-fox/pen/RgjgJN

```
audioSource = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
audioSource.connect(analyser);
```

Comment out these lines to see that music plays fine until the analyzer is connected.

How can I stop the analyzer / visual effects from disrupting the music?

Comment: you need to connect your audioSouce to the audioCtx.destination.

Comment: Thank you! This was the specific thing I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an analyser not too long ago:
https://codepen.io/Cooorsin/pen/zKPbEm
and
http://simple-music-player.corsins.space/

If you want the entire code of the second link I can put it on GitHub for you.

I've used the following code to initialize the audio:

```
function initAudio(src){
  var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  audioContext = new AudioContext();
  analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser(); 

  //analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 1;
  analyser.fftSize = barAmount;

  audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = src;


  audio.addEventListener('canplay', function(){
      sourceNode = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
      sourceNode.connect(analyser);
      sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
      audio.play();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was missing the last connection to audioCtx.destination.

Comment: Glad I could help :)